# Quartz beforeExecute and afterExecute methods

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Does Quartz have analogs of ThreadPoolExecutor's beforeExecute and afterExecute methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the TriggerListener and JobListener interfaces.